# forward slashes in red, checked not working

Tags: html

Ok this feels really basic...but its giving me a run for my money.  I have put together a page with really basic tags. break tags, input tags, etc.  I came across a problem when I used a "checked" on one of the radio buttons in my form.  It wasn't "checking" properly.  So I looked at the page source and noticed a lot of the forward slashes were in red.  The "checked" was also in red.  Comparing that to a normal page, I found that that is not the case there.  Does anyone know whats going on?  It seems to keep the page from functioning properly, and a google search on this turned nothing out...

Comment: If you post the offending markup, that would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You have bad markup. Validate your page to help isolate.

Comment: Do you have a recommended way to validate?